# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name') for [event.target.name]: event.targe.value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, controlled-component

I'm creating a simple controlled component form in react. When I console log event.target.name on onChange event it logs fine but when I setState using computed property name of the object in javascript it gives me an error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')`
This never happened before and I've created many working projects where I created the form similar way. Could you please explain why all of sudden these issues occurring to me?
[image]
import "./Contact.css";
import React from "react";

```
const Contact = () => {
  const [contactFormValues, setContactFormValues] = React.useState({
    fName: "",
    lName: "",
    email: "",
    phone: "",
    message: "",
  });
 
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setContactFormValues((prevValues) => ({
      ...prevValues,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value, // Here, this line gives me error
    }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(contactFormValues);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div className="contact-form">
        <div className="contact-container">
          <div className="left-section">
            <div className="title">
              <h1>Write Us</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="contact-sub-row">
                <label className="contact-label">First Name</label>
                <input
                  className="contact-input"
                  type="text"
                  name="fName"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value={contactFormValues.fName}
                  required
                />
              </div>

              <div className="contact-sub-row">
                <label className="contact-label">Last Name</label>
                <input
                  className="contact-input"
                  type="text"
                  name="lName"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  // value={contactFormValues.lName}
                  required
                />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="contact-sub-row">
              <label className="contact-label">Email</label>
              <input
                className="contact-input is-success"
                type="email"
                name="email"
                onChange={handleChange}
                // value={contactFormValues.email}
                required
              />
            </div>

            <div className="contact-sub-row">
              <label className="contact-label">Phone</label>
              <input
                className="contact-input"
                type="tel"
                placeholder="1-123-456-7890"
                maxlength="20"
                name="phone"
                onChange={handleChange}
                value={contactFormValues.phone}
                required
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="right-section">
            <div className="your-message">
              <label className="contact-label">Message</label>
              <textarea
                className="contact-textarea"
                name="message"
                placeholder="Write text here..."
                onChange={handleChange}
                value={contactFormValues.message}
                required
              ></textarea>
            </div>
            <div className="contact-btns">
              <button className="submit-btn" onClick={handleSubmit}>SEND MESSAGE</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Contact;
```

Comment: this seems fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-graehg?file=App.tsx

Comment: Is it happening when you try to type in a specific input or do all of them throw an error?

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka yes does but, I've attached the screen grab of my error. I mean why it's not working for me while it does work somewhere else?

Comment: @AviCohenNehemia it occurs when I try to input, usually after the first letter in an input.

Comment: any inputs without the `name` property?

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka if it was the case then it'd not have worked in stackblitz either :). You can cleary see in the code, I've just 5 inputs and all have their names and values as well.

Comment: You can try binding the event with handleChange method. Your code works fine on my machine.

Comment: @binding? why binding? this is not a class component.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the inputs in a form tag element. 
and try this:

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setContactFormValues({ ...contactFormValues, [name]: value });
}
```

I've done this in our very last project.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to explain what makes you think mine is different from yours? Why do you think not using destructuring is the cause of my error?